# Propper way to bind ng-model in ng-repat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this

```
"List": {
"lorem": 127,
"ipson": 5.5,
"dolor": 29,
"sit": 19}
```

Then i use the following ng-repeat code to create a table with input fields

```
<table>
        <tr ng-repeat="(item, weight in settings.list">
            <th>
                <input ng-model="item"></input>
            </th>
            <th>
                <input ng-model="weight"></input>
            </th>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Now I obviously want the ng-model to update the parent scope, but i have no idea how to do it

Comment: i don't get the obvious part ;p

Comment: Be more specific. The inputs update `$scope.cart` and `$scope.tara` in the controller that is assigned to this part of code. What is not working?

Comment: If you want it to update to items inside list (`ng-repeat = 'item in list'`), your ng-model should be `item.cart`.. if you want a global value which shared by all the items, I think you can do sth like: $scope.all.cart={}, then inside your html, ng-model='all.cart'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to do have a list like that :

```
list : [
  {
   name : "lorem",
   weight : 127
  },
  {
   name : "haha",
   weight : 12
  }
];
```

and then :

```
<table>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in settings.list">
            <th>
                <input ng-model="item.name"></input>
            </th>
            <th>
                <input ng-model="item.weight"></input>
            </th>
        </tr>
</table>
```